# Connection with remote services Streaming API

Tags: java, twitter-oauth, scribe, twitter-streaming-api, twitter-rest-api

I had a problem while using Streaming API in Java. Visited many sites, but unable to locate problem with code.

Here's the code i'm using :

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import com.github.scribejava.core.builder.ServiceBuilder;
    import com.github.scribejava.apis.TwitterApi;
    import com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuth1AccessToken;
    import com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuth1RequestToken;
    import com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuthRequest;
    import com.github.scribejava.core.model.Response;
    import com.github.scribejava.core.model.Verb;
    import com.github.scribejava.core.oauth.OAuth10aService;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    public abstract class TwitterStreamConsumerr {

        private static final String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL = "https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json";

        public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
            final OAuth10aService service = new ServiceBuilder()
            .apiKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
            .apiSecret("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
            .build(TwitterApi.instance());
            final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("=== Twitter's OAuth Workflow ===");
            System.out.println();

            // Obtain the Request Token
            System.out.println("Fetching the Request Token...");
            final OAuth1RequestToken requestToken = service.getRequestToken();
            System.out.println("Got the Request Token!");
            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("Now go and authorize ScribeJava here:");
            System.out.println(service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken));
            System.out.println("And paste the verifier here");
            System.out.print(">>");
            final String oauthVerifier = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println();

            // Trade the Request Token and Verfier for the Access Token
            System.out.println("Trading the Request Token for an Access Token...");
            final OAuth1AccessToken accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, oauthVerifier);
            System.out.println("Got the Access Token!");
            System.out.println("(if your curious it looks like this: " + accessToken
            + ", 'rawResponse'='" + accessToken.getRawResponse() + "')");
            System.out.println();

    // Now let's go and ask for a protected resource!
            System.out.println("Now we're going to access a protected resource...");
            final OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL, service);
            service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
            final Response response = request.send();
            System.out.println("Got it! Lets see what we found...");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(response.getBody());

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("That's it man! Go and build something awesome with ScribeJava! :)");

            OAuthRequest request1 = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL, service);
            request1.addHeader("version", "HTTP/1.1");
            request1.addHeader("host", "stream.twitter.com");
            request1.setConnectionKeepAlive(true);
            request1.addHeader("user-agent", "Twitter Stream Reader");
            request1.addBodyParameter("track", "java,heroku,twitter"); // Set keywords you'd like to track here
            service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
            Response response1 = request.send();


        // Create a reader to read Twitter's stream
            BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response1.getStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader1.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }
```

When i run this program with debugger, i found that exception occur whis code reaches to the end on line shown below.

[image]

And Exception is :

```
    Exception in thread "main" com.github.scribejava.core.exceptions.OAuthConnectionException: There was a problem while creating a connection to the remote service: https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json
        at com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuthRequest.send(OAuthRequest.java:39)
        at com.mycompany.twitterstreamconsumer.TwitterStreamConsumerr.main(TwitterStreamConsumerr.java:81)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: connect in progress
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnection.java:517)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.setRequestMethod(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:374)
        at com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuthRequest.doSend(OAuthRequest.java:45)
        at com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuthRequest.send(OAuthRequest.java:37)
```

I'm using Maven and my pom.xml is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>TwitterStreamConsumer</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.scribejava</groupId>
                <artifactId>scribejava-apis</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

I would be very thankful if someone help me to locate this problem.

Comment: Hi @wonderb0lt, here i tried to enhance my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that problem is here, you  created

`OAuthRequest request1 = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL, service);`

but in code beelow you using

`Response response1 = request.send();` instead of 
`Response response1 = request1.send();`